# Use option to drag windows (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager

In a lot of window managers for X11, you can move windows by clicking anywhere on them and dragging while holding down the alt key. Is there anyway to get similar functionality on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a built-in way, that I know of, but [MondoMouse](http://www.atomicbird.com/mondomouse/) claims to add the capability. (Not free.)

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the following solutions are exactly what you're looking for, but they're something, at least.

1. Enable Spaces (Apple menu > System Preferences > Personal > Exposé & Spaces > Spaces > To activate Spaces: set a key). Then, when you press the key you've assigned, you will see an overview of your desktop(s) and can drag windows from any spot, not just their title bars.
2. You can move background windows by holding the Command key while dragging. This only works with title bars, however.

Comment: 3. Windows with the same medium grey appearance as all title bars have nowadays (that was once the "brushed metal" appearance, if you go back that far) can usually be dragged from any free stretch of that title-bar-style medium gray color that isn't part of a button or other control. This usually includes free parts of the toolbar and any tab bar, and often includes status bars at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Not what I'd like, but thanks for the command trick to drag background windows, that will be useful